# Make Concurrent Request Upto N times

Tags: java, multithreading

I have `Q` Query which needs to be submitted to the DataSource, I want to execute each Queries `N` number of times with maximum concurrency `C`.

Code which i wrote:

```
 @Override
    public void run() {
    
     try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, properties)) {
        
       semaphore.acquireUninterruptibly();
         try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(SQL)) {
                    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()
                   // Do Something
         }finally {

                    semaphore.release();
         }
     }
}
```

My Main Method:

```
        Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(concurrency);

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(N);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            executorService.submit(new QueryTester(semaphore,SQL));
        }
```

Currently, I am executing Single Queries with `N` threads, if there are `Q` Queries available each need to executed `N` times how I can make changes to code?

So I don't have run my method `Q` number of times for each available Queries

Comment: Why do you need both a semaphore and a fixed thread pool? Wouldn't having a thread pool of size `C` and submitting all tasks (`Q*N` tasks) be sufficient?